# Set value from input as value in state

Tags: reactjs

### I have task:

- When the user will write some word into the **input** and presses button **SetValue**, this word should be set as a value in the `inputValue` field.

But I don't have experience with inputs. And know how implement this task...

**file App.js**:

```
import SetValue from "./SetValue.js"
const App = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    inputValue: ""
  });

// THERE SHOULD BE SOME METHOD or TWO METHODS WHO IMPLEMENTS MY TASK

return (
    <div>
      <SetValue/>  
   </div>
  );
};
```

And I have input with button (**file SetValue.js**)

```
export default () => {
  return (
    <div>
        <input type="text" />
        <button>SetValue</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

What do I need to add in the code of the **App.js** file and the **SetValue.js** file to implement the task?

Comment: Do you mean `SetValue` is `Search` in your `App.js` file?

Comment: @technogeek1995 I edit question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to pass a function that edits the state and pass the value of the state to the child component. In the child component, you can access those values through the props variable. In the parent component, you implement a function that makes a copy of the state, updates the copy of the state, and updates the component's state. You access the value of the input field by setting an `onChange` function. However, you'll have to set the `value` of the input field since you're creating a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). You may want to review [this article](https://dev.to/stanleyjovel/simplify-controlled-components-with-react-hooks-23nn) for additional assistance.

#### App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import SetValue from "./SetValue.js"

const App = () => {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    inputValue: ""
  });

  const setValueFromInput = value => {
    const copyOfState = { ...state };
    copyOfState.inputValue = value;
    setState(copyOfState);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <SetValue
        state={state}
        setValueFromInput={setValueFromInput}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

#### SetValue.js

```
const SetValue = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={props.state.value}
        onChange={event => props.setValueFromInput(event.target.value)}
      />
      <button>SetValue</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SetValue;
```